# Make it so table cell don't expand vertically because of content

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have an html table, I fill this table with content taken from a database however there's one side effect I want to avoid, I want to avoid the cells expanding vertically to accomodate the content, I tried using `table-layout:fixed`, `overflow:hidden` or setting `max height` for rows but none of these worked.

Any idea how I can fix this?

This is my table component (using vue):

```html
<table class="entry_table_container" v-if="posts" style="overflow:hidden; table-layout:fixed;">
  <tr>
    <th class="entry_table_header" width="5%">Categoría</th>
    <th class="entry_table_header" width="5%">Titulo</th>
    <th class="entry_table_header" width="5%">Contenido</th>
    <th class="entry_table_header" width="5%">Imagen</th>
    <th class="entry_table_header" width="5%">Descripción</th>
    <th class="entry_table_header" width="5%">Visible</th>
    <th class="entry_table_header" width="5%">Acción</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row" v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
    <td>{{ post.postcategory.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ post.title }}</td>
    <td v-html="post.body"></td>
    <td>
      <div class="image_row_container" :style="'background-image:url('+post.image+');'"></div>
    </td>
    <td v-html="post.imageDescription"></td>
    <td class="checkbox_row" style=""><input type="checkbox" class="entry_checkbox" :checked="post.isVisible"></td>
    <td class="row_buttons_container">
      <button class="row_buttons_button boot_blue" @click="showModal({ activePostModal: 'PostUpdateModal', post: post})" type="button" title="Editar"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
      <button class="row_buttons_button boot_red" @click="showModal({ activePostModal: 'PostDeleteModal', post: post})" type="button" title="Eliminar"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `height` or `max-height` won't work on `table` element, try to set the `height` or `max-height` on the `td` elements

Comment: Have you tried `no-wrap`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your td content with a div and then set its height

```css
.heightCont{
  height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table class="entry_table_container" v-if="posts" style="overflow:hidden; table-layout:fixed;">
  <tr>
    <th class="entry_table_header" width="5%">Categoría</th>
    <th class="entry_table_header" width="5%">Titulo</th>
    <th class="entry_table_header" width="5%">Contenido</th>
    <th class="entry_table_header" width="5%">Imagen</th>
    <th class="entry_table_header" width="5%">Descripción</th>
    <th class="entry_table_header" width="5%">Visible</th>
    <th class="entry_table_header" width="5%">Acción</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row" v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
    <td><div class="heightCont">{{ post.postcategory.name }}</div></td>
    <td><div class="heightCont">{{ post.title }}</div></td>
    <td v-html="post.body"></td>
    <td>
      <div class="image_row_container" :style="'background-image:url('+post.image+');'"></div>
    </td>
    <td v-html="post.imageDescription"></td>
    <td class="checkbox_row" style=""><input type="checkbox" class="entry_checkbox" :checked="post.isVisible"></td>
    <td class="row_buttons_container">
      <button class="row_buttons_button boot_blue" @click="showModal({ activePostModal: 'PostUpdateModal', post: post})" type="button" title="Editar"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
      <button class="row_buttons_button boot_red" @click="showModal({ activePostModal: 'PostDeleteModal', post: post})" type="button" title="Eliminar"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```